# Why Emacs (as daemon) gives 1 more frame than is opened?

Tags: emacs

If Emacs was started with "--daemon" then `(frame-list)` returns 2 frames when only 1 is opened

```
(frame-list)
(#<frame  *Minibuf-1* - Emacs 24.3.50.1 0x11c7270> #<frame F1 0xb94ac8>)
```

If you start Emacs without daemon flag - no "F1" buffer will be there.

How to reliably determine what frames were opened by a user? Are there any specific properties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a "physically invisible" frame  (even though `frame-visible-p` says otherwise) associated with initial terminal where the daemon was started. I suspect that a sole reason for its existence is that emacs is not ready to run with no frames at all, and it's hard enough to fix it.

For filtering it out I would use this test:

```
(string-equal "initial_terminal" (terminal-name <frame>)) 
;;; => t for the "pseudo-"frame created by emacs -daemon
```

There might be better tests, but as far as I know this one is reliable enough: `terminal-name` returns something like `"/dev/tty"` for tty frames and the X11 display name like `":0"` for X11 frames (I can't recall what it returns on other platforms, like in a Windows console window, but I believe it can't be  `"initial_terminal"` by accident).